# K&R - section 1.9: understanding character arrays (and incidentally buffers)

Tags: c, arrays, char

Let's start with a very basic question about character arrays that I could not understand from the description in the book:

- Does every character array end with '\0'?
- Is the length of it always equal to the number of characters + 1 for '\0'?

  - meaning that if I specify a character array length of 10 I would be able to store only 9 characters that are not '\0'?
  - or does the '\0' come after the last array slot, so all 10 slots could be used for any character and an 11th non-reachable slot would contain the '\0' char?

Going further into the example in this section, it defines a getline() function that reads a string and counts the number of characters in it.
[you can see the entire code here (in this example getline() was changed to gline(), since getline() is already defined in newer stdio.h libraries)](https://github.com/soffes/k-and-r/blob/c9b4b1357179b7dbdd2fd3e5cdbbd0b0505d62a8/examples/1.9-1.c)

Here's the function:

```
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

It is explained that the array stores the input in this manner:
`[h][e][l][l][o][\n][\0]`
and the function will return a count of 6, including the '\n' char, 
but this is only true if the loop exits because of a '\n' char. 

If the loop exits because it has reached it's limit, it will return an array like this (as I understand this):

`[s][n][a][z][z][y][\0]`
now the count will also be 6. 

Comparing both strings will return that they're equal when clearly "snazzy" is a longer word than "hello",
and so this code has a bug (by my personal requirements, as I would like to not count '\n' as part of the string).

Trying to fix this I tried (among many other things) to remove adding the '\n' char to the array and not incrementing the counter,
and I found out incidentally that when entering more characters than the array could store, the extra characters wait in the input buffer,
and would later be passed to the getline() function, so if I would enter:
"snazzy lolz\n"
it would use it up like this:
first getline() call: `[s][n][a][z][z][y][\0]`
second getline() call: `[ ][l][o][l][z][\n][\0]`

This change also introduced an interesting bug, if I try to enter a string that is exactly 7 characters long (including '\n') the program would quit straight away because it would pass a '\0' char to the next getline() call which would return 0 and would exit the while loop that calls getline() in main().

I am now confused as to what to do next.
How can I make it not count the '\n' char but also avoid the bug it created?

Many thanks

Comment: It is not that you HAVE to add a NULL at then end but several standard functions use that NULL at the end to understand when to stop. The length of the Character array and the length of the string it contains are two different things: you can declare a character array of 100 bytes use it to store a (NULL terminated) 10 bytes string.

Comment: @mauro`NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_. You mean ASCII-`nul` or `'\0'`. And that's what makes a `char []` a C "string".

Comment: @Olaf it depends from the compiler but... you're right! What I meant was the ASCII value zero ('\0)

Comment: @mauro: No, it does not depend on the compiler. It is defined in the standard. Even _iff_ it is `#define NULL 0` (legal bad uncommon in C),  `NULL` should not be used other than in pointer context. Not only for readbility, but also portability.

Comment: @Olaf :  Strictly NUL is the ASCII mnemonic for a null character, so mauro was not really incorrect.   However I agree that it is clearer to distinguish between a null-pointer and a null-character because if the `NULL` macro, however while in code it would be incorrect, in natural language, where null character and null pointer are valid terms; unqualified null in this context I would say is acceptable.

Comment: @Clifford: I would have not complained about using "_null character_". But just `NULL´ (all uppercase) normally means the macro. I don't mind if someone calls me nit-picky when it comes to programming; the compiler and CPU are too and as I tend to quickly crash (bei it intendend or not) incorrect code, I actually have to.

Comment: @Olaf : He'd have had to have written `NULL` rather than NULL to reach my *"hang on, someone on the Internet is wrong and must be corrected"* threshold. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf: I was referring to compilers (not standards) but ok let's talk about standards and, if I'm wrong, please correct... C99 standard section 6.3.2.3 "**An integer constant expression with the value 0**, OR such an expression cast to type (void *), is called _null pointer constant_". Then (section 7.17) "NULL which expands to an implementation defined _null pointer constant_". Given the previous definition of "_null pointer constant_" doesn't this means that - for example - (char)0 is a valid NULL?

Comment: @mauro: 1) C99 is not valid C standard. See the C-info page. 2) The first section is irrelevant when talking about the macro `NULL`. Note that the standard uses a different numbering. Relevant is  7.19p3 . Left the numbering apart, the standard clearly talks about **a** _null pointer constant_ (note the `a` which implies there can be more than one actually). Given that you must not use `NULL` in an integer context. There is likely already a question here; iff(!) not, feel free to post one, this is neither the place to tutor nor to explain the standard.

Comment: @Olaf, I agree: this is not the place to tutor/explain C, compilers & standards. Let's close this here.

Comment: @dr15 : You have asked a number of questions here; the ones about he language with respect to arrays and strings probably belong in a separate question to the ones about how to modify `getline()` to meet your requirements.  Consequently are likely to get answers that only address the highlighted bullet-point questions and ignore the other buried questions.  In future you might do well to post separate questions in order to get faster answers to all your questions.

Comment: @Clifford : Thanks, you live you learn... That's what I'll do next time.

Answer (score 4):

There is a *convention* in C that strings end with a null character. On that convention, all your questions are based. So

- Does every character array end with '\0'?

No, It ends with \0 because the programmers put it there.

- Is the length of it always equal to the number of characters + 1 for '\0'?

Yes, but only because of this convention. Thereto, for example you allocate one more byte  (char) than the length of the string to accommodate this \0.

Strings are stored in *character arrays* such as `char s[32];` or `char *s = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);`

Comment: I think "convention" is a bit understated. The C standard defines string literals to end with a null byte, so this is a bit more than convention, I think, since the standard defines it that way.

Comment: @cad: Not really. C does not have a string type, thus the `nul` terminator _is_ really just convention of the libraries. It is just that the core-language has this support for automatically adding it to a _string literal_, which simplifies the programer's job here (otherwise we would have even more questions about string overflow UB). Note that `char a[5] = "Hello";` is very well legal and does not append the terminator.

Comment: @cad, when developing C, K&R could also have chosen for a long as the first field of a string containing the length, or a negative offset to find this length field. Whatever they would have chosen is their convention.

Answer (score 2):

> Does every character array end with '\0'?

No; strings are a special case - they are character arrays with a nul (`\0`) terminator.  This is more a convention than a feature of the language, although it is part of the language in-so-far that literal constant strings have a nul terminator. Moreover in a character string, the nul appears at the end of the *string*, not the end of the *array* - the array holding the string may be longer that the string it holds.

So the nul merely indicates the end of a string in a character array.  If the character array represents data other than a string, then it may contain zero elements anywhere.

> Is the length of it always equal to the number of characters + 1 for '\0'?

Again you are conflating strings with character arrays.  They are not the same.  A string happens to use a character array as a container.  A *string* requires an *array* that is *at least* the length of the string plus one.

> meaning that if I specify a character array length of 10 I would be
>   able to store only 9 characters that are not '\0'?

You will be able to store 10 characters of *any* value.  If however you choose to interpret the array as a string, the string comprises only those characters up-to and including the first nul character.

> or does the '\0' come after the last array slot, so all 10 slots could
>   be used for any character and an 11th non-reachable slot would contain
>   the '\0' char?

The nul is at the end of the string, not the end of the array, and certainly not after the end of the array.

> Comparing both strings will return that they're equal when clearly
>   "snazzy" is a longer word than "hello",

In what world are those strings equal?  They have equal length, not equal content.

> and so this code has a bug (by my personal requirements, as I would
>   like to not count '\n' as part of the string).

Someone else's code not doing what *you* require is hardly a bug; that implementation is by design and is identical to the behaviour of the standard library [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) function.  If you require different behaviour, then you are of course free to implement to your needs; just omit the part:

```
if (c == '\n') {
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
}
```

To explicitly flush any remaining characters in the buffer the removed code above may be replaced with:

```
while(c != '\n') {
    c = getchar() ;
}
```

One reason why you might not do that is that the data may be coming from a file redirected to stdin.

One reason for retaining the `'\n'` is that enables detection of incomplete input, which may be useful in some cases.  For example you may want all the data in the line, regardless of length and despite a necessarily finite buffer length, a string returned without a newline would indicate that there is more day to be read, so you could then write code to handle that situation.

Comment: Thanks, you've definitely cleared up the confusion I had between string and character arrays.